# How to use C++ code from C#?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, pinvoke

I need to use [this](http://oblita.com/interception.html) library (`Interception`). It is written in `C++`. Briefly, it lets you manipulate input from keyboard or mouse.
What I need to do is to use some of those calls from `C#`.

I'm not sure which path to follow. So far I've read that you could use `Pinvoke` to use `C++` code inside `C#`.

I have many questions regarding `PInvoke`:
1) Do `Pinvoke` libraries need to be in a specific system path to be found (e.g. `system32`)?

I've read that getting the right `PInvoke` signatures can be hard and error prone, and since I couldn't find any `PInvoke` signature for `Interception` in *PInvoke.net*,
2) Does that mean that I should desist on using `PInvoke`?

I've also seen, but didn't go much into detail, that in Visual Studio, when you create a project, you can create a `Visual C++->CLR->Class Library`.
3) Should I use this to build an assembly linking `Interception`? Could this assembly be used within `C#`?

Anyways, if a `C#` alternative to `Interception` exists, I would use that instead.

Comment: From a quick glance it looks like you should be OK with p/invoke, since it is a flat API using handles, like the winapi itself, and not doing member function calls on classes.  A C++/CLI wrapper is also a good choice, of course.

Comment: Also, p/invoke uses the default DLL search path if you don't provide a full path.  So putting the DLL in your program directory should work well.

Comment: Had a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) yet? It can generate a wrapper API around your C++ code that your C# code can use.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Ok, I'll keep that in mind if others paths get awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, if the library is in the same path as the executable, it will work.

2) You only use PInvoke with C functions, not C++ objects. So using PInvoke to directly call Interception library is probably out of the question.

3) You can create a C++/CLI library that links to Interception. But you will have to create your own .NET objects to wrap the pure C++ objects in Interception.

I would recommend you read a bit about coding CLR in C++. Making a CLR wrapper in C++/CLI is probably the cleanest way to go.

Comment: FWIW it is named C++/CLI

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oops! Corrected.

Comment: OK. Your first point is lacking a little detail and the second point is plain wrong. In this case, the library is quite callable with pinvoke. There are no classes and the interop is very routine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan For the first point: yes, I could have explained the whole algorithm of how DLLs are searched for. But I think just knowing you can simply put the DLL in the same directory as your executable is very probably what he needed to hear. For the second point: The question said that Interception was written in C++ (after all, look at the title of the question!), so I assumed (it seems wrongly) that it consisted of C++ objects.

Answer (score 2):

A p/invoke import is resolved using the system [DLL search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx). So the DLL need not be in the system directory. It just needs to be in the DLL search path. Indeed, you should not put it in the system directory because the system owns that. The best place is the same directory as the executable. That location is searched first.

The library in question has a rather small header file that presents a C style interface. It's a rather simple candidate for p/invoke. You certainly won't find any translations on pinvoke.net but it's also not too hard to translate this library.

You could certainly use C++/CLI for your interop. This would add another layer and another module. On the other hand you would have type safety right the way down the chain. If you are not confident and experienced with interop and p/invoke then it is possible that C++/CLI will be more productive.

Comment: Might be a bit tricky encoding the union-which-is-not-a-union (`InterceptionStroke` - `InterceptionKeyStroke` - `InterceptionMouseStroke`)  Needs a bit of `FieldOffsetAttribute` to make that work right in C#.

Comment: @Ben It's just two structs, and then the classic C# p/invoke union with `FieldOffset(0)`. One wonders why the unmanaged code doesn't use a union.